# Zero set of convolution of two integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let zero set of two integrable function $f,g$ be $Z_f,Z_g$ respectively. What can we say about the zero set of their convolution $f*g$ defined to be 
$$ (f*g)(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int_\mathbb{R}g(x-y)f(y)dy.$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the support of a functions is defined as $$supp(f)=\overline{\{x:f(x)\neq0\}}$$
Assuming that the integral for convolution exists then it can be shown that 
$$supp(f*g)\subset \overline{supp(f)+supp(g)}$$
So for the zero sets 
$$supp(f*g)^c \supset  \overline{supp(f)+supp(g)}^c$$
Since $Z_f=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $supp(f)=\overline{f^{-1}(\{0\})^c}$

We have
$$\big(\overline{Z_{f*g}^c}\big)^c\supset \big(\overline{\overline{Z_{f}^c}+\overline{Z_{g}^c}}\big)^c $$

Comment: Hey $Z_f\neq (supp(f))^c$

Comment: you are right but you can at least say something about containment

Comment: $supp(f)=\overline{f^{-1}(\{0\})^c}$

Comment: Can we say anymore?

Comment: not to my knowledge.  I think it has to do with the fact that convolution is defined as an integral.